# Custom permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

At the moment our Wordpress Permalink structure is:

http://www.website.com/article-title-goes-here/

For specific needs, I need a setup such as this:

```
http://www.website.com/bob/article-title-goes-here/
http://www.website.com/claire/article-title-goes-here/
http://www.website.com/dom/article-title-goes-here/
```

Although the article will be the same, I need the /bob/  parts of the URL to be accepted but to all land to the same article.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could change the .htaccess and add a new redirection rule or If you are not familiar with that use the following plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/
The plugin enables you to set specific redirection rules. You can even set a pattern so every URL containing /bob/ will be redirected automatically.